# Partial view MVC set ID on Html.Beginform to get right submit function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, model-view-controller

I have a problem with my partial views. I have two partial views that loads correctly and everything works fine there. But on form.submit only one function is triggered no matter what button the user is clicking. I have set an id on my @html.beginform but it doesn't seem to work correctly!

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="fade in active hidden" id="reconiliation">
                @Html.Partial("UploadReconciliationFile")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="" id="payment">
                @Html.Partial("UploadBankgiroFiles")
            </div>
        </div>
```

**UploadReconciliationFile partial View**

```
<div id="reconciliationdiv" class="hidden">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadReconciliationFile", "Payments", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "UploadReconciliationFile", @class = "merchant-form" }))
  {
    <div class="left-col">
        <div class="form-group">
            @if (Model.Installations.Any())
            {
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Installations, new { @class = "h4" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, Model.Installations, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Installations, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            }
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-button">
        <div class="btn btn-primary" id="fileUploadDiv">
            <input type="file" name="files" class="hidden" multiple="multiple" id="file" onchange=" form.submit() " />
            <label for="file" id="fileLabel">Välj filer</label>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**UploadBankgiroFiles partial view**

```
<div id="bankgirodiv">
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadBankgiroFiles", "Payments", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "UploadBankgiroFiles", @class = "merchant-form" }))
{
    <div class="left-col">
        <div class="form-group">
            @if (Model.Installations.Any())
            {
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Installations, new { @class = "h4" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, Model.Installations, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Installations, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            }
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-button">
        <div class="btn btn-primary" id="fileUploadDiv">
            <input type="file" name="files" class="hidden" multiple="multiple" id="file" onchange="form.submit() " />
            <label for="file" id="fileLabel">Välj filer</label>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Any suggestions and improvments on my code?

Comment: Try with different id values for the submit buttons, they both have "file" value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with different id:s on the submit buttons.

```
 <div id="bankgirodiv">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadBankgiroFiles", "Payments", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "UploadBankgiroFiles", @class = "merchant-form" }))
    {
        <div class="left-col">
            <div class="form-group">
                @if (Model.Installations.Any())
                {
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Installations, new { @class = "h4" })
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, Model.Installations, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Installations, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                }
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-button">
            <div class="btn btn-primary" id="fileUploadDiv">
                <input type="file" name="files" class="hidden" multiple="multiple" id="files" onchange="form.submit() " />
                <label for="files" id="fileLabel">Välj filer</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```